# Eclipse formatter inserts whitespace before method on linebreak

Tags: java, eclipse, whitespace, checkstyle

Using Eclipse Juno I've got the following issue using the Java code formatter:

If a method call leads to a line break, Eclipse inserts a whitespace before the "dot" of the method invocation (_ shall denote the whitespace)

```
int nbo = new Foo()//linebreak
    _.method();
```

Unfortunately this whitespace triggers a Checkstyle warning (NoWhitespaceBefore rule). Is there some possibility to stop eclipse inserting the whitespace? Or is it a Checkstyle configuration issue?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: Hi John, Did you try my way? Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

You can increase **Maximum line width** to 120 or bigger number.

1. On menu Windows -> Preferences
2. Navigate to Java -> Code Style -> Formatter
3. Click on Edit button to open a new dialog
4. On *Line Wrapping* tab, change **Maximum line width**
5. Finally, change *Profile name* and click OK

Comment: Unfortunately maximum line width is predefined for this project and must not be changed.

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve this either by changing the formatter settings or by changing the Checkstyle configuration.

**Option 1 - Formatter Settings** *(for Eclipse 4.3, but should be the same for Juno)*

- Window → Preferences → Java → Code Style → Formatter → Edit
- Line Wrapping → Function Calls → Qualified Invocations
- Set to *Do Not wrap*

**Option 2 - Checkstyle Config**

- Remove the `DOT` token from the *NoWhitespaceBefore* rule:

```xml
<module name="NoWhitespaceBefore">
    <property name="tokens" value="SEMI,POST_DEC,POST_INC"/>
</module>
```